# React native mediaStore public photos

Tags: react-native, gallery, photo, mediastore

I have an app which allows you to store photos and videos like a diary. These are stored in public directories so that other apps can access and view these such as the standard photos app. Also so that the user doesn't lose their photos when they uninstall the app.

However, android 11 I believe only allow this via using mediaStore.

My app is a react native app, I can't find any npm packages that allow you to do this via mediaStore. Does anyone no of a library or have a suggestion of how I can store files in a public location still within react native??